Power bi generate pages
We have a Power BI report with multiple pages, each connected to specific data. To obtain certain information, we have to repeat the same steps multiple times. We want to know if Power BI can automatically generate dynamic pages based on the data, to simplify access to this information.
We have a Power BI report with multiple pages, each connected to specific data. To obtain certain information, we have to repeat the same steps multiple times. We want to know if Power BI can automatically generate dynamic pages based on the data, to simplify access to this information

Short answer : No.
Currently, it is not possible to generate report pages dynamically in Power BI.
More links :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Create-multiple-pages-dynamically/td-p/987418
